# LinuxOnAndroid - How to start an activity

Tags: android, linux, ubuntu, embedded-linux

I'm currently using LinuxOnAndroid ubuntu on top of my android device.
I want to start an activity through linux, the FAQ says it's possible and even shows how, but I cant manage to get it working.

Any tips?

EDIT: I'm using the command line, not the GUI

Thanks in advance,
Gal Gavish

Answer (score 0):

try 
`am start -n yourpackagename/.activityname`

Comment: exec: app_process: not found